# Prisma + Docker + NextJS - docker-componse - Where to put "npx prisma db push"

Tags: docker, next.js, prisma

I want to dockerize my app (Prisma 4.9.1, NextJS 12, PostgreSQL). The idea is, that you can clone the repo, type `docker-compose up` and everything works just fine.

The problem is: I don't know where put `npx prisma db push`. I've tried already multiple locations, but it's not working. Any ideas?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18 AS dependencies

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

FROM node:18 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate
RUN yarn build:in:docker

FROM node:18 AS deploy

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --from=build /app/public ./public
COPY --from=build /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=build /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=build /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/prisma ./prisma

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: myhost
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: splitmate
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
  splitmate-app:
    image: splitmate
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: deploy
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/app/postgres-data
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://root:password@myhost:5432/splitmate?schema=public&connect_timeout=60
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

The container gets built and starts. But as soon as the code tries to access the database, I get this error:

```
features-splitmate-app-1  | Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:
features-splitmate-app-1  | 
features-splitmate-app-1  | 
features-splitmate-app-1  | The table `public.Account` does not exist in the current database. {
features-splitmate-app-1  |   message: '\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     'Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     'The table `public.Account` does not exist in the current database.',
features-splitmate-app-1  |   stack: 'Error: \n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     'Invalid `prisma.account.findUnique()` invocation:\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     'The table `public.Account` does not exist in the current database.\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '    at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31941:13)\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '    at RequestHandler.handleAndLogRequestError (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31913:12)\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '    at RequestHandler.request (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:31908:12)\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '    at async PrismaClient._request (/app/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:32994:16)\n' +
features-splitmate-app-1  |     '    at async getUserByAccount (/app/node_modules/@next-auth/prisma-adapter/dist/index.js:11:29)',
features-splitmate-app-1  |   name: 'Error'
features-splitmate-app-1  | }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18 AS dependencies

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn

FROM node:18 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=dependencies /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate
RUN yarn build:in:docker
COPY migrate-and-start.sh .
RUN chmod +x migrate-and-start.sh

FROM node:18 AS deploy

WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

COPY --from=build /app/public ./public
COPY --from=build /app/package.json ./package.json
COPY --from=build /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=build /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --from=build /app/prisma ./prisma
COPY --from=build /app/migrate-and-start.sh .

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["./migrate-and-start.sh"]
```

**migrate-and-start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

npx prisma generate
npx prisma db push
node server.js
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: myhost
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: root
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: splitmate
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: unless-stopped
  splitmate-app:
    image: splitmate
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: deploy
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/app/postgres-data
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://root:password@myhost:5432/splitmate?schema=public&connect_timeout=60
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar solution to this answer:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /app

# Bundle files
COPY . .

#Update npm 
RUN npm install -g npm@latest

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose port 3000
EXPOSE 3000

# Start app
CMD source migrate-and-start.sh
```

migrate-and-start.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
npm run build
npx prisma generate
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
npm run start
```

It solves problem when prisma can't find postgres DB ready too.